# how do I remove from tuples in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this

```
[
  ('px', Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00')),
  ('px', Timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00')),  
  ('px', Timestamp('2017-09-01 00:00:00')),  
  ('px', Timestamp('2017-10-01 00:00:00')),  
  ('px', Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:00:00'))
]
```

and want to remove the `'px'` keeping only the timestamps as a tuple.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also unpack your data using `list comprehension`:

```
final = [(v,) for _, v in yourlist]
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit and the solution. As you can see I am a beginner but really appreciate this forum and your help

Comment: You're welcome. If any answer fills your need, try to accept it. Clic on the green check box under the answer's score.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice off the first items in a *list comprehension*:

```
new_lst = [x[1:] for x in lst]
```

The tuple slice gives you a new tuple, with the items at index 0 removed.